# Typescript type aliases and string interpolation

Tags: typescript, string, types, interpolation, alias

I've been using Typescript for a while and am currently working with type aliases which have the following form:

```
type Animal = "cat" | "dog";
let a1_end = "at";
let a1: Animal = `c${a1_end}`
```

As far as I understood, only the values "cat" or "dog" would be allowed for any variable of the type Animal. But strictly speaking, it should be possible since the result would be "cat", right? I'm just asking since I get the error that the only allowed values for any variable of the type Animal can be either "cat" or "dog" when I'm running this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `a1_end`'s type is inferred to be *string*.

```
let a1_end = "at";
//  ^? string
```

So the use of a string literal here actually produces a type that can't be assigned to `"cat"`:

```
let a1: Animal = `c${a1_end}`
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ type is `c${string}`
```

and since `` `c${string}` `` is not assignable to `"cat"`, you get an error (because any string that starts with "c" is not assignable to the string "cat").

If you annotate the type or tell TypeScript in any way that `a1_end`'s type is `"at"`, it works:

```
let a1_end = "at" as "at";
let a1_end = "at" as const;
let a1_end: "at" = "at";
const a1_end = "at";
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqePrm)

Answer (score 1):

Since you assign  `c${string}` to variable a1 which is type of Animal you got error. (Because type '`c${string}`' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.)
I mean any string that starts with 'c' is not assignable to string "cat"

If you annotate the type or do `a1_end`'s type is "at", then your script works in TypeScript

Solutions:

1. The most simple way declare a1_end with const

```
  const a1_end  = "at"
```

With above solution you could assign easily type "at" to `a1_end`

If you want to keep declaring variable with `let`, just foloow second solution

2. Assign type of "at" into `a1_end`

```
  let a1_end : "at" = "at"
```

or

```
let a1_end  = "at" as "at"
```

For more information to learn type aliases in TypeScript I recommend reading this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/typescript-type-alias